# App Store shows cloud icon for Xcode 10.3, how to update from installed version 10.2.1?

Tags: mojave, xcode, mac-appstore, software-update

I'm running MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 with Xcode 10.2.1 installed.  The Mac App Store doesn't show any update option for 10.3. In App Store, Account -> Purchases section shows Xcode with a Cloud with a down arrow icon, as if Xcode is not installed and needs a re-download.

The last time I had this issue and pressed the Cloud icon, I had issue with synchronising my GitHub account and had to reinstall everything.

How can I update to Xcode 10.3?

PS: [Can't update Xcode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232802/cant-update-xcode) recommends bypassing the App Store, but I had used the App Store in the past to install and update it. Given the download size, something that is guaranteed to work would be great.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232802/cant-update-xcode

Comment: Thank you but this Xcode was not installed from outside the App Store. Also, it was updated to 10.2.1 via the App Store... Finally, I don't see any update button, just the cloud one, which is what one sees when the system doesn't see a software installed. If the download would be any smaller I would gladly try things, but I need something that is sure to work. Thank you