# What is the correct version of xcode for mojave 10.14.4

Tags: mojave, xcode

I installed Mojave on VMWare. Below are the details.

[image]

I downloaded and installed xcode 9 and it was not compatible with this mojave version.
How can I get to know about the correct version of xcode for mojave 10.14.4?

Comment: Note - any question on Xcode versions ages out to “ancient history” territory quickly. We can list what a specific combination do, but there are apps to manage all the versions and this quickly becomes a “dev code maintainance” subjective question IMO.

Answer (score 12):

- [Wikipedia: Xcode: 11.x series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_11.x_(since_SwiftUI_framework))

For macOS 10.14.4, Xcode versions compatible are: Xcode 10.2 - 11.3.1.

Xcode 11.4 onwards requires macOS Catalina, 10.15.2 though with some hacks it can be made to work on 10.14 also. [How to run Xcode 11.4 on macOS Mojave 10.14.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61013626/)

With a free Apple Developer account, one can download older versions of Xcode (all the way back to Xcode 2.3 as well as new as 11.5 at [Apple Developer: More Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)

Also a nice catalogue at [Xcode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com/).

Comment: Another good reference for this info is https://xcodereleases.com/