# Xcode stuck on installing

Tags: macos, install, xcode, mac-appstore, big-sur

I just reset my 2018 MacBook Air and upgraded it to macOS Big Sur.

One of the first things I did was install Xcode through the App Store.

It downloaded just fine, but got stuck on installing. I've tried restarting my computer, but it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: I have the same exact issue. I've tried everything to stop it from continuing to sit here "installing". It's been 2 days now. [![Xcode stuck on install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFkmM.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFkmM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Ditch App Store and use the [Apple Developer](http://developer.apple.com/) site to download the xip file and extract it to install Xcode.

- [Can't update Xcode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232802/cant-update-xcode)

---

Alternative is to find the file App Store downloaded, and if it's an archive, expand it manually.

Since it's a huge file, it would be easy to find using any of the apps listed at

- [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space)